# Using an ArrayList to add new objects in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having trouble understanding an ArrayList. I am writing a program using 3 classes Customer, Video, and Invoice.  In the code below I am creating a new customer to add to set ArrayList but I feel I am trying to treat it as if it were an array. I want the user to be able to add another customer object and use a counter "i" and run through the series of questions to add to that customer object. i realize some of this is quite a mess.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Prog4 {


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList <Customer> customer = new ArrayList <Customer>();
        int i = 0;
        char ans;

        do
        {

            System.out.print("Customer name: ");
            String name = in.next();
            customer.add(i,).setName(name);

            System.out.print("Street Address: ");
            String streetAddress = in.next();
            d1.setStreetAddress(streetAddress);

            System.out.print("City: ");
            String city = in.next();
            d1.setCity(city);

            System.out.print("State: ");
            String state  = in.next();
            d1.setState(state);

            System.out.print("Zipcode: ");
            String zipcode = in.next();
            d1.setZipcode(zipcode);

            System.out.print("Phone Number: ");
            String phoneNumber = in.next();
            d1.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

            customer[i] = new Customer(name, streetAddress, city, state, zipcode, phoneNumber);

            System.out.print("Would you like to enter in a new customer (y/n)? ");
            String answer = in.next();
            ans = answer.charAt(0);
        }while(ans == 'y');


    }

}
```

Comment: what the hell is `customer.add(i,)`? That cannot compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would recommend to set values to the Customer object and then do customer.add(Customer object)

Something like :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Customer {
    private String name;
    private  String streetAddress;
    private  String city;
    private  String state;
    private  String zipcode;
    private  String phoneNumber;



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }



    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



    public String getStreetAddress() {
        return streetAddress;
    }



    public void setStreetAddress(String streetAddress) {
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    }



    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }



    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }



    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }



    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }



    public String getZipcode() {
        return zipcode;
    }



    public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }



    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }



    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        List <Customer> customerList = new ArrayList <Customer>();
        char ans;

        do
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer(); 
            System.out.print("Customer name: ");
            customer.setName(in.next());

            System.out.print("Street Address: ");
            customer.setStreetAddress(in.next());

            System.out.print("City: ");
            customer.setCity(in.next());

            System.out.print("State: ");
            customer.setState(in.next());

            System.out.print("Zipcode: ");
            customer.setZipcode(in.next());

            System.out.print("Phone Number: ");
            customer.setPhoneNumber(in.next());

            customerList.add(customer);

            System.out.print("Would you like to enter in a new customer (y/n)? ");
            String answer = in.next();
            ans = answer.charAt(0);
        }while(ans == 'y');

        for(Customer c: customerList){
            System.out.print(c.getName());

        }

        for(int i=0; i<customerList.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(customerList.get(i).getName());

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: alright thank you very much. this was a big help. i was having trouble with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support operator overloading and classes from the Java standard library are just normal classes.

This means that the only time it makes sense to use [] is with arrays (and not ArrayList which is a class in the Collections Framework).  If you need to know what methods ArrayList has available, please refer here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html (specifically I think you're interested in the add() method)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should rename

```
ArrayList <Customer> customer = new ArrayList <Customer>();
```

to

```
ArrayList <Customer> customers = new ArrayList <Customer>();
```

so everybody (including author) knows that it is some container with customers.

Next, this is an syntax error:

```
customer.add(i,).setName(name);
```

Comma is used to separate arguments, like max(2, 4, 5). You are adding a number, but this container can have only customers inside, also arraylist automatically increments indexes when adding so dont worry about some i.
So if you want to add a customer to ArrayList customers, you first need to create one.
Something that could work...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList <Customer> customers = new ArrayList <Customer>();
    char ans;

    do
    {

        System.out.print("Customer name: ");
        String name = in.next();
        //customer.add(i,).setName(name); you dont need this

        System.out.print("Street Address: ");
        String streetAddress = in.next();
        //d1.setStreetAddress(streetAddress);
        //these parameters are in constructor of class customer

        ...

        System.out.print("Phone Number: ");
        String phoneNumber = in.next();
        //d1.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

        Customer customer = new Customer(name, streetAddress, city, state, zipcode, phoneNumber);
        customers.add(customer); //first create, then add

        System.out.print("Would you like to enter in a new customer (y/n)? ");
        String answer = in.next();
        ans = answer.charAt(0);
    }while(ans == 'y');


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to the above answers, try the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Prog4 {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList <Customer> customers = new ArrayList <Customer>();
    // int i = 0; Why is this needed ?
    char ans;

    do
    {

        System.out.print("Customer name: ");
        String name = in.next();

        System.out.print("Street Address: ");
        String streetAddress = in.next();

        System.out.print("City: ");
        String city = in.next();

        System.out.print("State: ");
        String state  = in.next();

        System.out.print("Zipcode: ");
        String zipcode = in.next();

        System.out.print("Phone Number: ");
        String phoneNumber = in.next();

        Customer tempCustomer = new Customer(name, streetAddress, city, state, zipcode, phoneNumber);
        customers.add(tempCustomer);

        System.out.print("Would you like to enter in a new customer (y/n)? ");
        String answer = in.next();
        ans = answer.charAt(0);
    }while(ans == 'y');

    in.close();
  }

}
```

Note that the add() method adds an element to the next index in the ArrayList, you do not need to specify an index with square brackets [].

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html